# how to disable and enable select in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, ios5, jquery-selectors

I am doing web app for iOS using jQuery.
I have a  select in one page. According to the requirement I have to disable it.

```
      <select name="select-choice-a" id="selectCardType" data-native-menu="false">
           <option value="select">Select Card Type</option>
           <option value="A">American Express</option>
           <option value="M">Master Card</option>
           <option value="V">Visa</option>
      </select>
```

I have 2 scenario 'The user can come to the page directly or form another app by url scheme'

I have used

`$('#selectCardType').selectmenu('disable');`
       or

'$('#selectCardType').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); `

But it is not working for me in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help. I got the solution.

create one global variable `var onceVisitedCardpage = false;`

if you have visited that page then make this variable as **true**

then check the state of that variable before coming to that page

```
    if(onceVisitedCardpage)
        $('#selectCardType').selectmenu('disable');
    else
        $('#selectCardType').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

By this way I manage to handle both the senario.

Answer (score 0):

If I disable a simple select ... it is disabled in any browser (including iOS)

demo: http://jsbin.com/unezod/2/

```
$("#selectCardType").prop("disabled", true);
```

This is how the link above shows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! 
It is working if you disable it on load of the page.

if, Once you go to that page (which contains select) and then with respect to some condition you are trying to disable it, then it was not happening that time.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330101/how-to-enable-and-disable-selectmenu-jquery-mobile/65046090). I had the same issue, was trying to use:

```
$("selectId").selectmenu("disable");
```

It wouldn't work until I added a # in front of the ID, i.e.

```
$("#selectId").selectmenu("disable");
```

Now it works.